# sending raw data directly from RAM

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, asio

in a SoC solution, the fpga is saving a lot of integer values directly in the RAM.
This Data(the integers) can be seen by the processor on the other side who should send this data over the network without modifying it using the asio library.
Until now this Data was not too big and I copied it to a vector and I send it over the Ethernet without problem (see the code please).
On a current project the amount of the data has been increased (about 200MB) and I would like to send it directly from the ram without copying it a vector before. Of course I will split this to parts.
Is there a way to send this raw data directly from a RAM pointer of type void (void *ptr) or there is a better way to do that ?

Thanks in advance

```
std::vector<int> int_vect;
for( uint32_t i=from_index ; i<=to_index ; i++ )
{   
     int_vect.push_back(my_memory_ptr->get_value_axis(....));
}
asio::write(z_sock_ptr->socket_, asio::buffer(int_vect));
```

Comment: Well you have a pointer to the beginning of the data, I assume? Just use that as the "source" for the send call.

Comment: Is the system super-latency sensitive?

Comment: @SergeyA the device should run for weeks and the memory would be easily full..
the FPGA side is latency sensitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.** One of the overloads of `asio::buffer` provides [exactly this functionality:](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html)

```
mutable_buffer buffer(
    void * data,
    std::size_t size_in_bytes);
  » more...
```

**If the data is contiguous,** we can use it like this:

```
void* data = /* get data */; 
size_t size = /* get size */; 
asio::write(z_sock_ptr->socket_, asio::buffer(data, size));
```

Comment: Thanks .. it seems to be what I need ! will test it tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to create asio buffer from raw data, it is essentially just a non-owning array view:

```
asio::write(z_sock_ptr->socket_, asio::buffer{p_data, bytes_count});
```